# How to save an array to a file 

Tags: python, arrays, save

I want to know how to save an array to a file. You already helped me a lot, but I have more naive questions (I'm new to Python):

```
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE 
NAME123 
line3 
line4 
line5 
line6 
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE 
NAME434543 
line3 
line4 
line5 
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE 
NAME343566 
line3 
line4
```

I am currently have this code, but it's save only the **last item** from the array no the all listed in the `items_grep`. How to fix this?

```
items = []
with open("test.txt", mode="r") as itemfile: 
    for line in itemfile: 
        if line.startswith("@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE"): 
            items.append([]) 
            items[-1].append(line) 
        else: 
            items[-1].append(line)      
#
# list to grep
items_grep = open("list.txt", mode="r").readlines()
# writing files
for i in items:
    if i[1] in items_grep:
        open("grep.txt", mode="w").write("".join(i))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your file is only showing the last value is because every time you open the file with the `w` flag, it erases the existing file.  If you open it once and then use the file object, you'll be fine, so you'd do (note, this is not a very clean/pythonic way of doing it, just being clear about how the open command works)

```
myfile = open("grep.txt", "w")
for i in ...
    if i[1] ...:
         myfile.write(i + '\n')
```

Easy way to handle this would be to do a list comprehension first and then join, e.g.:

```
newstr = '\n'.join([''.join(i) for i in items if i[1] in items_grep])
```

Then just write the entire string to the file at once. Note that without adding the `\n` between items, you won't end up with each item on a new line, instead they will all be added one after the other without spaces.

You should also consider using the `with` keyword to auto close the file.

```
with open("grep.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(newstr)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! The problem was with the **join**, can you please describe more details. Why the last only?

Comment: updated to add the answer to the question. you reopen the file in every iteration of your for loop (so it erases every time)

Comment: @JohnAmraph So, the reason that the `'\n'.join()` fixed the problem for you is because it combined all your file writes into one statement (so none of them overwrote each other :P)

Comment: So, it's kind of join-ing the writing?

Comment: @JohnAmraph clever :) but in a sense, it did combine all the writes into one.  The big takeaway though, is that every time you open a file for writing with the `w` flag, whatever is already in the file is erased. (so you might want to, for example, read whatever is in the file first and then add to it).

Comment: If you wanted to open a file multiple times without erasing ("truncating") the content, you'd have to first close the file, then reopen it in append mode `open(fname, 'a')`, rather than write mode `open(fname, 'w')`. Write mode always assumes you want to discard the previous content, and this is also how most programs (text editors, e.g.) save files.

Comment: @JohnAmraph , btw - if this answer solved your problem, it would be great if you could accept the answer (by clicking the check underneath the vote count). That way, people will know it's resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I marked already as solved - but then forgot to thank you, then unmarked to do it...So, thank's a lot! (already marked)